# Passing a datagridview from another form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Display data from datagridview to another form , i tried different methods but none of them seems to work , so here is what i tried.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
    Dim frm As New EvidentnaLista



    frm.TextBoxMaticen.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()

    frm.TextBoxOddelenie.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxPrezimeIimeNaNositel.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxLekLiceIAdresa.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxSrodstvo.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxGradSelo.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxOpstina.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxDrzava.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxStalnoMesto.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxBrojNaLicna.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxZanimanje.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxKadeEVraboten.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxBrojNaZdrKniska.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxBrojNaUpat.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxMkbBroj.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(14).Value.ToString()
    frm.TextBoxPodatociZaBlz.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(15).Value.ToString()
    'frm.TextBoxDatum.Text = selred.Cells(17).Value.ToString

End Sub
End Class
```

The form is not displaying my data

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour] then spend some time formatting your code to look like code to make it easier for people to understand your question (there are help buttons and formatting tools on the toolbar)

Comment: Hello plutonix i just updated the code , sorry

Comment: you create a new form instance in that method, but never show it, is that the problem?  How did the DGV get populated?  Its better to pass the *data* to the other form and let it populate its own controls

Comment: how can i pass the data to the other form ?

Comment: i updated the questin with the other method i used

Comment: The form is not showing because...you dont show the form. add `frm.Show()` to the end of the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needs just the frm.show to display the form